# jquery/php rerun php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've looked a lot through Stackflow and google but didn't find a fitting answer.

So basicly I run a php script to generate a string. It is random and will change everytime you reload the page.

I hide that string with jquery and show it with a simple button. Now my question is how can I use the Button to rerun the php script, without reloading the whole page, because that wouldn't be very efficent.

Comment: It's called [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Read this doc, should help you: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rerun the PHP script using an ajax call. Include a jQuery and use this when the button is clicked (and you ignore the script output):

```
$.get("test.php");
```

If you want to print the script output with javacript, use it like this

```
$.get( "test.php", function( data ) {
  alert("Script content: "+data);
});
```

Full documentation available here
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 0):

I've found another workaround which works pretty decent when your page is build a certain way.

I use multiple .php files to create my site with include() so I just have to reload that specific page.

```
<button type="button" onclick="$('main').load('p/text.php');"> Generate </button>
```

What this does:

It only works inside the ('main') where I only included p/text.php earlier in my index file. Then everytime you press this button it will load it again. Works perfect for me and requires no ajax

I think if I want to I could just put my element that I want to reload into a single .php file and only reload this inside a div.

Thanks for the answers though :)